# Is it safe to store a password in a Node.js file?

Tags: node.js, security, heroku, server, passwords

I have deployed a simple app to Heroku with a JavaScript file serving an HTML page via Express. The code is pulled from a private Git repo.

Now, I have a password stored in this JavaScript file and my question is: can an user find that password? It's only used in requests made from Node to external resources.

This is part of the server-side JavaScript code where I serve the page:

```
const app = express();
const express = require('express');

const password = ******:

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/dist/shop-info-angular'));

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/dist/shop-info-angular/index.html'));
});
```

Comment: Is it a client-side or a server-side JavaScript file? Do you send the file itself to the user's browser, or does it generate an HTTP response and send that? It's probably best if you [edit] your question and include the relevant portion of your file (make sure to take the password itself out). There's definitely a better option than hard-coding passwords, though.

Comment: I updated the question, please let me know if I can add more info, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this example your JavaScript file will run on the server and just send the response to the user. As long as the `index.html` that you're sending in your response doesn't also contain the password you should be fine.

However, Heroku offers a [better way to configure applications](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars) that is especially well-suited to sensitive information like passwords. Update your code to get the password from the environment:

```
const password = process.env.PASSWORD;
```

and set an environment variable on Heroku:

```
heroku config:set PASSWORD=mysecretpassword
```

You can also use environment variables locally, but note that they'll be different from the ones you set on Heroku. After all, they're *environment*-specific. Something like [`dotenv`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) can help.